# Can we scan for Ibeacons in background through IOS API, by only providing Major and Minot number as Parameters?

Tags: ios, swift

My application is to scan for all Ibeacon devices around in background mode. The limitation is that, I only know the Major and Minor number of the Ibeacons. Once the Ibeacon is detected, My code will extract the UUID from the scanned device. That UUID is important for me which is variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Scanning for iBeacons is done using `CLBeaconRegion` objects, and all initializers for this class force you to pass the UUID. Wildcards are only possible for `major` and `minor`.